# Streaming avi to a red5 server

Tags: video, stream, ffmpeg, red5, xuggler

I have a problem with Red5 Media Server.
I installed it on Windows machine and I'm trying to stream *avi file to the server using ffmeg:

`ffmpeg -i testfile.avi -re -acodec libfaac -ar 22050 -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/test`

According to the console ffmpeg is streaming to a server.

So I opened Publisher application to see if is it working or not.  `http://localhost:5080/demos/publisher.html`

I clicked connect, and i got this
`NetConnection.Connect.Success`

next I chenged stream name to test and pressed play
`NetStream.Play.Start`

but it didn't work.
I will be really greatful if someone can help me.

Kind Regards
Babel

Answer (score 0):

While streaming a video to red5 server using ffmpeg just check red5 log for any error. I am getting error in red5 while streaming avi file

```
 org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Error decoding buffer
```

So that the video not yet streamed. That's why you are not able to see. This may be a reason. I am using red5-0.9 and ffmpeg version N-38632.